# DocumentBeforeSave event to save documents in both .docx and .htm format results in infinite loop of saving

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to save a Word document in HTM format besides the normal DOCX.

I want to intercept all commands the user can use to save/close a document. The major problem is intercepting the X Close Window application in the right upper corner.

I tried to use the `DocumentBeforeSave` event.

- in class module EventClassModule:

```vb
Public WithEvents appWord As Word.Application

Private Sub appWord_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
   If Len(ActiveDocument.path) > 0 Then
       MsgBox "I got you", vbOK
       SalvaActiveDocumentDocxAndHTM
       Cancel = True
   Else
       Cancel = False
   End If
End Sub
```

- in a regular module:

```vb
Public Sub SalvaActiveDocumentDocxAndHTM()
    Dim sNomeFile As String, sPath As String
    Dim vTipo As WdViewType
    Dim ObjWordDoc As Word.Document, objWordActDoc As Word.Document
    Set objWordActDoc = Application.ActiveDocument
    With objWordActDoc
        .Save
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            vTipo = .ActiveWindow.View.Type
        End With
        sPath = ActiveDocument.path
        sNomeFile = sPath + Application.PathSeparator + RemoveExtensionFromFileName(.Name)
        .SaveAs2 fileName:=sNomeFile + ".htm", FileFormat:=wdFormatHTML, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        'open again file docx
        Set ObjWordDoc = Documents.Open(sNomeFile & ".docx")
        .Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
        With Application
            .ActiveWindow.View.Type = vTipo
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    End With
    Set ObjWordDoc = Nothing
    Set objWordActDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

I cannot avoid the infinite loop of saving. I tried with a boolean inserted before and after the call of `SalvaActiveDocumentDocxAndHtm`.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1265416/vba-word-problem-with-documentbeforesave-in-macro

Comment: I know. I'm sorry. I posted also here because My browser frezed and I thougth the post was lost.

Answer (score 0):

Every `Save` will trigger the `DocumentBeforeSave` event, so you need to set a flag to indicate that your code is running.

```
Public WithEvents appWord As Word.Application
Private SavingAsHTML As Boolean

Private Sub appWord_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not SavingAsHTML Then
        If Len(ActiveDocument.Path) > 0 Then
            SavingAsHTML = True
            SalvaActiveDocumentDocxAndHTM
            SavingAsHTML = False
            Cancel = True
        Else
            Cancel = False
        End If
    Else
        'allow the save to complete
        Cancel = False
    End If
End Sub
```